# On the tensor product of two coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let,$R = \mathbb K[x_0,...,x_n]. A = \mathbb K[x_0,...,x_{n-1}]$, where $\mathbb K$ is an algebraically closed field. My question is the following :

Is it true that $R/(x_1,...x_n)^2 \otimes R/(x_n) = A /(x_1,...,x_{n-1})^2$ ?

I know that $R/(x_1,...x_n)^2 \otimes R/(x_n) = R/(x_1,...x_n)^2 + (x_n)$ as we have $R/I \otimes R/J \cong R/I+J$.

But then how can we show that $R/(x_1,...x_n)^2 + (x_n) \cong A /(x_1,...,x_{n-1})^2$ ?

If we define a map $\phi :A \to R/(x_1,...x_n)^2 + (x_n)$ in an obvious way then I can see the map is surjective and $(x_1,...,x_{n-1})^2 \subset Ker (\phi)$,But how to show the equality?( This is basically coming from an attempt to compute scheme theoretic intersection of two closed subschemes of a scheme)

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The same way you show any map is an isomorphism: product a two-sided inverse. Producing an explicit inverse is not hard here. Alternatively, you can make use of the fact that the two rings you care about are both finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: For any ideal $I \subset J$ in $R$ we have $(R/I) /(J/I) \cong R/J$. In your case $I = (x_n)$ and $J =(x_1, \dots, x_n)^2 + (x_n)$. Now what is $J/I$?